# Двусторонне направленый список(нужен исходник)

Tags: delphi, pascal

Реализовал двусторонне направленный список, хотел бы теперь почитать исходники подобных вещей, для внедрения оптимизаций.(красотульки аля property пока не интересны, процедуры которые присутствуют в классе - реализованы, и именно подобного интересует исходник)
И попутный вопрос, как хранить строку в record, точнее как выделять память под такой record, т.к. на данный момент строка фиксированной длинны.

```
z0_double_list  = class
  Constructor Create;
  Destructor Free;
  Function GetId(aName:string):Integer;
  Function GetName(aid:Integer):string;
  Procedure Add(nID:Integer; nName:string);
  Procedure Del(dID:Integer);                 Overload;
  Procedure Del(dName:string);                Overload;
Private
  First : Pz0_list_item;
  Last  : Pz0_list_item;
  temp  : Pz0_list_item;
end;
```

Comment: @ToRcH565, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

[[@Torch565](/users/10415/torch565)](/users/10415/torch565), а в чем вас не устраиваеть `Дженерики` ?

- [Generics](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE2/en/Generics.Collections.TDictionary_%28Delphi%29)
- Вот здесь тоже [доки](http://interactiveasp.net/blogs/spgilmore/archive/2009/12/23/using-generics-in-delphi.aspx)

**UPD**

Если в рекордах то :

```
type SomeRecord = record
First : Pz0_list_item;
  Last  : Pz0_list_item;
  temp  : Pz0_list_item;
end;

...........................
```

myVar:SomeRecord;

```
....................
```

Потом здесь надо декларировать function add():Somerec; чтобы добавить новую `item`, а для установки длины динамически есть [setLength](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SetLength)

Comment: 1) Их нет в delphi7(все проэкты переводить на студию желания нет)
2) Я с ними не знаком
3) Задача именно разобратся со списками.

Собсно уже нашел десяток реализаций листов) и вопрос не актуален)